# Sendkey to hidden CMD

Tags: c#

I recently created a UI tool that contains a recreated command prompt. The problem is, I have no way of killing, for example, a continuous ping. The normal method of doing that would be to press CTRL+C to kill the running command. I am trying to find a way to send a keypress, for example, CTRL+C, to the hidden CMD from my UI.

So you can visualize in your head what is going on here, I have a side panel where you select which tool in the UI you want to use. I have a RichTextBox named `DoAllTheThingsTextBox` which I use to, well, do all the things. I also have another box that is mainly used to enter the name of a computer but I repurposed it so I wouldn't have to make another textbox, which is called `CompNameBox`. If I type `ping 8.8.8.8` into CompNameBox and press enter, it works like a cmd and displays the output in DoAllTheThingsTextBox. Say I type `ping 8.8.8.8 -t`. It will start a continuous ping that you can stop by pressing CTRL+C. Since I am not typing directly into CMD, I can't stop the command once it has started unless I kill it from task manager. but that kills the whole cmd which I was using.

I have tried to use the sendkey code but have not been able to figure out how to send it to the running cmd on button press.

```
    private void ToolSelectionBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Display Panel
        if (ToolSelectionBox.SelectedItem != null && ToolSelectionBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Command Prompt")
        {
            CmdPrompt = new Process();
            CmdPrompt.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            CmdPrompt.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            CmdPrompt.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            CmdPrompt.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            CmdPrompt.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            CmdPrompt.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            CmdOutput = new StringBuilder("");
            CmdPrompt.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
            CmdPrompt.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortErrorHandler);
            CmdPrompt.Start();
            CmdPrompt.BeginOutputReadLine();
            while (!CmdPrompt.HasExited)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            if (DoAllTheThingsButton.Visible == false)
            {
                //This is to check if a button used for other function is the UI is visible
                //If it isn't then you are likely using the cmd option.
                CmdPrompt.StandardInput.WriteLine(CompNameBox.Text);
                CompNameBox.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (DoAllTheThingsTextBox.InvokeRequired) { DoAllTheThingsTextBox.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
        else
        {
            DoAllTheThingsTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
            DoAllTheThingsTextBox.SelectionStart = DoAllTheThingsTextBox.TextLength;
            DoAllTheThingsTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
    private void SortErrorHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (DoAllTheThingsTextBox.InvokeRequired) { DoAllTheThingsTextBox.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortErrorHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
        else
        {
            DoAllTheThingsTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
            DoAllTheThingsTextBox.SelectionStart = DoAllTheThingsTextBox.TextLength;
            DoAllTheThingsTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent